# Facebook Wallpost hyperlink attachment/design

Tags: php, html, css, facebook, hyperlink

Is there anyway, or anyhow, i can design the attachment facebook wall makes from a link? When you post a link from a website, it takes a title, an image and description and so on, but how can i customize the link's design? So when people take my link, post it on their facebook wall, i've decided what the image shall be, and the description and title facebook takes when making the attachment?

Hope you guys understand. If not, make a comment, then i will try describe the question on another way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `meta` tags. Have a look at [facebook's Open Graph](http://ogp.me/) to check how it works.

Example:

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<title>The Rock (1996)</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
...
</head>
...
</html>
```